# Generating parameters for `docker run` through command expansion from .env files

Tags: bash, shell, docker, sh, posix

I'm facing some problems to pass some environment parameters to `docker run` in a relatively generic way.

Our first iteration was to load a `.env` file into the environment via these lines:

```sh
set -o allexport;
. "${PROJECT_DIR}/.env";
set +o allexport;
```

And then manually typing the `--env VARNAME=$VARNAME` as options for the `docker run` command. But this can be quite annoying when you have dozens of variables.

Then we tried to just pass the file, with `--env-file .env`, and it *seems* to work, but it doesn't, because it does not play well with quotes around the variable values.

Here is where I started doing crazy/ugly things. The basic idea was to do something like:

```sh
set_docker_parameters()
{
    grep -v '^$' "${PROJECT_DIR}/.env" | while IFS= read -r LINE; do
        printf " -e %s" "${LINE}"
    done
}

docker run $(set_docker_parameters) --rm image:label command
```

Where the parsed lines are like `VARIABLE="value"`, `VARIABLE='value'`, or `VARIABLE=value`. Blank lines are discarded by the piped `grep`.

But `docker run` complains all the time about not being called properly. When I expand the result of `set_docker_parameters` I get what I expected, and when I copy its result and replace `$(set_docker_parameters)`, then `docker run` works as expected too, flawless.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you very much!

P.S.: I'm trying to make my script 100% POSIX-compatible, so I'll prefer any solution that does not rely on Bash-specific features.

Comment: Your final method doesn't work with any of the variables containing whitespace. Use an array instead of a string.

Comment: @jordanm Hmm.. I checked and it's true that it works when I don't have spaces in any variable. Do you have in mind any good reference where I could look for how to use "arrays"?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: I'm seeing that arrays are not present in POSIX specification, are they really the only way to fix that problem? I think there's probably some workaround that does not involve copy-pasting variable definitions.

Comment: There is a POSIX example in the FAQ. POSIX shells can kind of emulate arrays with positional parameters.

Comment: Also, be aware that a JS-style `.env` file is *not* a shell file; it's probably best to either  make it docker-friendly so that you *can* use `--env-file`, or to make the process inside the image handle the `.env` file itself. In that case, you would just make it readable via a `--mount` option. Trying to parse it yourself just leaves you vulnerable to corner cases you haven't thought of yet.

Comment: @chepner I don't have control over those files, and neither on how the dockerized application consumes environment variables. The application expects environment variables, not a file, so that's what I feed to it. Besides that, I'm not really parsing anything, the syntax of those files is trivial, and I don't even have to deal with tokenization.

Comment: There is a difference between running `docker run -e foo="bar"` directly (the shell removes the quotes) and `x='-e foo="bar"'; docker run -e $x` (the shell does *not* remove the quotes). It's even worse if the file contains something like `foo="bar baz"`, because now `foo="bar baz"` isn't going to be one argument to `docker run`; it's going to be *two* arguments, `foo="bar` and `baz"`.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I'm not doing that in the end, but what you saw as my "solution", where I don't have any problem with spaces or quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments of @jordanm I devised the following solution:

```sh
docker_run_wrapper()
{
    # That's not ideal, but in any case it's not directly related to the question.
    cmd=$1

    set --; # Unset all positional arguments ($@ will be emptied)

    # We don't have arrays (we want to be POSIX compatible), so we'll
    # use $@ as a sort of substitute, appending new values to it.
    grep -v '^$' "${PROJECT_DIR}/.env" | while IFS= read -r LINE; do
        set -- "$@" "--env";
        set -- "$@" "${LINE}";
    done

    # We use $@ in a clearly non-standard way, just to expand the values
    # coming from the .env file.
    docker run "$@" "image:label" /bin/sh -c "${cmd}";
}
```

Then again, this is not the code I wrote for my particular use case, but a simplification that shows the basic idea. If you can rely on having Bash, then it could be much cleaner, by not overloading `$@` and using arrays.

Comment: You don't need `grep`; just put `[ -z "$LINE" ] && continue` as the first line of the `while` loop. What you have now shouldn't work, because you are setting the positional parameters in a subshell created by the pipe, not the shell executing the function.

Comment: This is also not "non-standard"; it's exactly *why* the `set` command lets you construct the value of `$@` in this way, and why `"$@"` behaves the way it does (compared to `"$*"`).

Comment: The grep should not create a subshell in any case (and as far as I can see, it does not). If I understand correctly how the shell works, the first command to be executed is the `while`, that starts listening to the pipe, and then `grep` is started, writing to the pipe.

Comment: Besides that, I was playing a little bit with it, passing the entire file with a redirection to the loop `while [...]; do [...]; done < ".env"` (and testing for empty lines inside the loop), and the code got buggy again for reasons I don't understand, so I guess I still have to learn some extra subtleties about this thing.